# sed regex to match multiple fields and values, including quotes

Tags: regex, awk, sed, quotes

I have a (space-separated) input file with lines such as:

```
field1=value1 field2="value 2" field3='value 3' field4="value '4'" ...
```

The number of fields varies depending of the line. In order to process properly such file, I would ideally like to `sed` it and obtain some tabulated-separated output such as:

```
field1 (tab) value1 (tab) field2 (tab) value 2 (tab) field3 (tab) value 3 (tab) field4 (tab) value '4'
```

The furthest I have been so far is with something such as `sed "s/\([a-z][a-z]*\)=\(['\"]\{0,1\}\)\(..*?\)\2/\t\1\t\3/g"` but way too far from solving my problem. My difficulty is to handle properly the absence or presence of delimiters (quotes) to the values. For the sake of elegance (or *geekness*), I am sticking to `sed`, but would also consider an `awk` alternative.

Thanks in advance for any help,

***Edit***: I am shocked to say, but @Jotne is right.

```
echo "field1=value1 field2=\"value 2\" field3='value 3' field4=\"value '4'\"" | sed "s/\([a-z][a-z]*\)=\(\([^ ][^ ]*\)\|'\([^'][^']*\)'\|\"\([^\"][^\"]*\)\"\)/\1\t\3\4\5\t/g"
```

does not work:
    field1=value1 field2="value 2" field3='value 3' field4="value '4'"`

Though the following (the idea behind is to parse an `audit.log` file) works:

```
root@XXX:~# tail -n 2 /var/log/audit/audit.log 
type=CRED_DISP msg=audit(1570385821.075:670): pid=32605 uid=0 auid=0 ses=399 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
type=USER_END msg=audit(1570385821.075:671): pid=32605 uid=0 auid=0 ses=399 msg='op=PAM:session_close acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
root@XXX:~# tail -n 2 /var/log/audit/audit.log | sed "s/\([a-z][a-z]*\)=\(\([^ ][^ ]*\)\|'\([^'][^']*\)'\|\"\([^\"][^\"]*\)\"\)/\1\t\3\4\5\t/g"
type    CRED_DISP    msg    audit(1570385821.075:670):   pid    32605    uid    0    auid   0    ses    399  msg    op=PAM:setcred acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success 
type    USER_END     msg    audit(1570385821.075:671):   pid    32605    uid    0    auid   0    ses    399  msg    op=PAM:session_close acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success
```

Why?

Comment: Do you need single quote around the `4` in `value '4'` when you do not have it around `3` in  `value 3`?

Comment: @Jotne Yes, I need to retrieve the value as is.

Comment: Can there be space in the filed name like this `"filed 10"=42`?  I suggest that you look at the system that create this mess of a data and upgrade it to some that gives more uniforme data.  I have never seen mix of singe and double quote around `value` fields.  What system do you use?

Comment: See my Edit above for details but no, field names are without spaces. File names can be included in values, hence the potential for space and quotes mess here.

Comment: `value` field with mixed quotes I have never seen, its either `field=data` or `field="my data"` but you do also have `field='my data'`. How come?  And form what system?  Can you please post real data, not just made up samples?

Comment: This is the `audit.log` file generated by _linux_ `auditd`. My Edit above is a real example:

`echo "type=USER_END msg=audit(1570385821.075:671): pid=32605 uid=0 auid=0 ses=399 msg='op=PAM:session_close acct=\"root\" exe=\"/usr/sbin/cron\" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'"`

Comment: I do use Splunk at work and Splunk (free 500MB/day) at home to analyze log data.  It handles most of this files automatically, + you do get a nice gui to look at.  Are other tools as well like elastic search etc.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/ \<([^ =]+)=("[^"]*"|'\''[^'\'']*'\'')/\t\1\t\2/g;s/=/\t/' file
```

The first substitution replaces all `=`'s and spaced fields except for the first field. The second substitution rectifies the first.

Comment: Just to unpack the payload of each pair in key=value this little improvement is possible:
sed -E 's/ \<([^ =]+)=("([^"]*)"|'\''([^'\'']*)'\'')/\t\1\t\3\4/g;s/=/\t/' file.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding:

> Edit: I am shocked to say, but @Jotne is right.

It does not work because of your regexp used in sed:

Do focus on the regexp for the key part in key=value pairs!

It should look like this:

```
echo "field1=value1 field2=\"value 2\" field3='value 3' field4=\"value '4'\"" | sed "s/\([a-z0-9][a-z0-9]*\)=\(\([^ ][^ ]*\)\|'\([^'][^']*\)'\|\"\([^\"][^\"]*\)\"\)/\1\t\3\4\5\t/g"
```

In the real data file there were no keys ending in digits so that it had matched!

By the way. @potong 's solution circumvents these details in an elegant way.

Kind regards.